# How to route Git/ssh protocole to "containered" git servers

Tags: git, docker, kubernetes

I have multiple git servers each with a couple repos.
I am trying to find a way to route git's ssh based trafic to the correct container (Each git server is a container containing the repos of a project) based on the desired project/repo.

I would like to avoid if possible having to distribute the connections on different ports of an "edge ssh mega" server.

All this is running on Kubernetes

[User requesting a repo for "Project 1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT68Z.png)

[User request a repo for "Project 2"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LffQV.png)

Any ideas? Or should I load balance and create a custom script like Githubs propriaty script "Gerve".

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need a service to terminate these connections and route them to the appropriate servers.  That's because a single SSH connection can actually contain multiple channels, each of which can be talking to a separate repository.  Moreover, you don't even know what repository you're connecting to until the encrypted connection has been set up and the user has authenticated.

I will point out that Kubernetes is a bad choice for Git connections, and especially SSH Git connections.  Git connections can last a long time because clones can be slow, and therefore it's hard to terminate a pod within a fixed period of time.  They also cannot be restarted.  Because of the aforementioned multiple SSH channels and the fact that an SSH connection can persist despite having no active channels, you're going to have to gracefully shut down the connection and not allow new ones once you know that the pod is going to need to terminate and then let the remaining connections finish.  If you terminate pods willy-nilly, your users will not think kindly of you.

You may want to read up more about the SSH protocol (such as in the RFCs) and common implementations, such as OpenSSH, and then re-evaluate your design.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had an alternative solution. I was hopping to create a stateless scalable git server that relies on storage for this reason. So instead of routing we could loadbalance the connections. I was hopping that two git servers could be both sending the same repo but to different users. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can certainly serve the same repo to different users from different servers.  You're still going to need to deal with the fact that an SSH connection can have multiple repository requests in one connection and the fact that Git operations tend to be long lived.  Kubernetes, at least as it's traditionally intended to be used, is not a good match for the latter.